# PHP-Dojo vs Java for large application

Tags: java, php, javascript, jquery, dojo

My company is in the infant stages of looking to building a team to develop a new platform to replace our existing system. UI/UX is extremely important since there are several thousand users. The current system is built in PHP with Zend.

I have been doing a lot of research and have thought about Yii with DoJo or something similar. I have also looked at the ZK framework if we decided to go the Java route. Whatever we choose the framework has to talk well with linux and be able to perform low level system operations like creating/updating files, etc.

At the end of the day I know very little about Java but the more I look it seems like all of the clean web applications are running Java.

Am I missing something here or am I on the right track thinking:

PHP = easier to train and hire people. Harder to get a rich UI

Java = harder to train and find developers. Clean UI more easily obtainable.

Comment: Dont know what is missing and isnt but what was the question again? Go with PHP + dojo ofc - IBM for One has run with this (on .nsf though) since age of days

Comment: My question is, do I need to look at Java in order to come out with a clean enterprise level UI? I know going either way we will choose they will scale. What is important to me is the UI. I am not opposed to either language/framework at this point I just want to make sure we make the right decision on the front end. I want to get a feel for what the community is doing in terms of large enterprise applications.

Comment: There is more than enough PHP and Java developers that it shouldn't matter on this point. I believe Java is easier to make performant, but unless you have several thousand *concurrent* users, this may not matter.

Comment: Facebook is using PHP... scalibility is not an issue :) And performance wise, Java sucks a looooot of resource, and the more activity you have the more you'll have to purchase high-end hardware just to support Java The Ogre :) As for UI... Java has always sucked badly for that, and PHP does no UI. JS all the way :)
Java is great for industrial backend code, not that much for the web.

Answer (score 3):

Choosing Java over PHP isn't much about a clean UI, is much more about the ability to grow in both size and complexity.

Don't get me wrong, I'm aware that there's a lot of big complex systems running fine with PHP, it's only that I find that Java has more support built in the platform for scalability.

You can have a clean, rich UI with both PHP and Java.

PHP - Easier and faster to get started. Harder to get around performance and scalability issues, even with proper knowledge.

Java - Harder to "get it right". If everything is done properly you'll reach performance problems later than with PHP... but with the proper knowledge it will be easier to find solutions.

But, as far as UX goes, you should go with what your developers are most confortable with. If the UX and backend logic are decoupled you can treat them as separated problems.